# Windows 10 software to batch remove white space from bottom of various images with different sizes

Tags: windows, image-editor

I need a Windows software to remove white space from images in bulk.

For example :

- image 1 : 1700px x 928px
- image 2 : 1700px x 850px
- image 3 :1700px x 1400px etc...

For each image white space is different in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is xnview batch editor "AutoCropt" it's working good.

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing the feature, thanks! And also price of the software.

Comment: xnview is a free software , https://www.xnview.com/en/

Comment: Please add that to the body of your answer, thanks! And please read Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality cheers!